# Question about automating Azure security center Auto provisioning - Extensions

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-security, azure-security-center

Please I am trying to automate azure security center auto provisioning using terraform but the resource **azurerm_security_center_auto_provisioning** seems inadequate. Setting **auto_provision = “On”** only turns on Log Analytics agent for Azure VMs but theres no way to enable **Policy Add-on for Kubernetes** and **Microsoft Dependency agent (preview)** extensions (at least non that i’ve found yet).

```
resource "azurerm_security_center_auto_provisioning" "example" {
  auto_provision = "On"
}
```

Also the the [Edit configuration] link in the portal under **Log Analytics agent for Azure VMs** takes you to a page where you can further configure your settings like **Connect Azure VMs to a different workspace** and you can Select the level of data to store such as **All Events, minimal, common and none** but I can’t seem to find a way to set all this up using terraform. Please is there some azurerm resource that I am unaware of or is this not a feature that is supported by the provider at this time.